# How to access the array in correct way in smarty?

Tags: php, arrays, smarty

The array named `$chapter_theory_details` is as follows :

```
Array
(
    [cs_class_id] => 2
    [cs_subject_id] => 8
    [chapter_id] => 103
    [chapter_cs_map_id] => 81
    [chapter_title] => Chemistry
    [chapter_data] => Everything related to literature
)
```

I've assigned this array to smarty template using following instruction :

```
$smarty->assign('chapter_theory_details', $chapter_theory_details);
```

Now I want to access the array key value `['chapter_data']` only. For it I wrote following code snippet in smarty, but couldn't get the desired result:

```
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0"> 
    <tr>
      <td align="center">
      {if $chapter_theory_details}  
      Chapter's Theory
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td align="center" valign="top">
      {foreach from=$chapter_theory_details item=chapter_theory} 
      <a href="#" onClick="get_chapter_theory_by_chapter({$chapter_theory.chapter_id}); return false;">{$chapter_theory.chapter_data}</a>
      {/foreach}</a>
      </td>      
    </tr>
      {/if}
  </table>
```

Instead of getting the desired output i.e.Everything related to literature, I'm getting the output `2 8 1 8 C E`. Can anyone help me out to get the desired output I need. Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

You are iterating over items in the `chapter_theory_details` in the `{foreach}` cycle. If you want to get just `chapter_id`, you don't have to iterate the array, just use `{$chapter_theory_details.chapter_id}` and remove `{foreach}`:

```
<td align="center" valign="top">
      <a href="#" onClick="get_chapter_theory_by_chapter({$chapter_theory_details.chapter_id}); return false;">{$chapter_theory_details.chapter_data}</a>
</td>
```

The result you get in your code was caused by following: As you iterated the `chapter_theory_details`, in `foreach` the variable `$chapter_theory` was containing values of the array (`2`, `8`, `103`, `81`, `'Chemistry'`, `'Everything related to literature'`) despite it's misleading name. When you accessed these simple values as an array (using `$chapter_theory.chapter_id`), you got just first character of the items.

Answer (score 0):

Try this : Remove the foreach in smarty

```
{assign var='key_val' value='chapter_id'}
{$chapter_theory_details.$key_val}
```

Ref: http://www.smarty.net/forums/viewtopic.php?t=10112

Answer (score 0):

You have `$chapter_theory` which has 1 item(array) which can be accessed without foreach.

To get chapter_id you need use `$chapter_theory_details.chapter_id`

Also there is one more pretty way to use foreach like in PHP

```
 {foreach $arr as $k=>$v}
```

More on http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/language.function.foreach.tpl

Answer (score 0):

If you only want the `chapter_data` value in smarty, use:

```
{$chapter_theory_details.chapter_data}
```

You don't need a `foreach` loop for this!